# The nature of dark side Rey

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

When Rey finds the wayfinder a dark side version of herself comes out. Is it just her hallucination, or something triggered by her presence?

Comment: The correct term I believe is "a reason to have Rey with a red light saber in the trailer"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rey herself recognises that the apparition is a [*Force Vision*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_vision) (e.g. not physically real). It was triggered by her touching an object that had been possessed by a strong Force user, in the same way that touching Luke's lightsaber in Maz's Palace made her have visions of the Jedi .

> A hooded figure materialized, glided toward her with inexorable
> purpose, dark cloak sweeping the ground. The figure practically
> radiated power, and something else…a cold and ravenous hunger.
>
> A red lightsaber appeared in the figure’s hand, chaotic like Kylo’s,
> with two parallel blades. Light from the blade finally illuminated a
> face as pale and gaunt as it was fierce.
>
> Rey gasped, stumbling backward. It was her. Her face, her form. Cold
> and dark, wearing a Sith cloak, whole at last.
>
> Horrified, she watched as the dark mirror Rey swung her blades apart,
> forming a long, fiery quarterstaff. It was the very saber she’d
> tentatively begun designing in her mind.
>
> **This couldn’t be real. It was a vision, nothing more.** But the dark
> Rey’s steps echoed when they met the floor, and her lightstaff reeked
> of ozone. Her power was incredible, intoxicating. Almost against her
> will, Rey began to reach with her hand…
>
> <sub><sup>[The Rise of Skywalker: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3):

It was a Force Vision, much like when Luke's experience in the [Dark Side Cave](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Side_Cave) on Dagobah. As I understand it, there is not a physical reality to it, but a warning of what she could become if she fell to the Dark Side.